# How to append two dataframes when column number differ in PostgreSQL in R

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

What I try to do is that bind rows in my PostgreSQL databes in matched columns like `rbindlist`'s (from `data.table`) `fill` argument.

In short, the table I'd like to see in my database is like this;

```
a <- data.frame(no=c(234,235,346),year=2012:2014,col1=c(1,1,1))
b <- data.frame(no=c(333,353,324),year=2014:2016,col2=c(2,2,2))
union_data_frame <- data.table::rbindlist(list(a,b),fill=T)

union_data_frame

     no  year  col1  col2
1   234  2012     1    NA
2   235  2013     1    NA
3   346  2014     1    NA
4   333  2014    NA     2
5   353  2015    NA     2
6   324  2016    NA     2
```

I tried it in `RPostgres` in this way;

```
library(RPostgres)

a <- data.frame(no=c(234,235,346),year=2012:2014,col1=c(1,1,1))
b <- data.frame(no=c(333,353,324),year=2014:2016,col2=c(2,2,2))

drv <- dbDriver('Postgres')
con <- dbConnect(drv,user='postgres',dbname='dummy_db')


dbWriteTable(con,'dummy_table',a,append = T,row.names = F)
dbWriteTable(con,'dummy_table',b,append = T,row.names = F)
```

But it doesn't work and fields an error because the second table (`b`) doesn't have a column called `col2`.

How to append tables by only common columns ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to:

1. identify which columns are missing,
2. `alter table` those new columns into existence, and then
3. upload the data, assuming all data in the first that are missing in the second are null-able.

```r
### pg <- dbConnect(...)
dbWriteTable(pg, "some_table", a)
newcolumns <- setdiff(colnames(b), dbListFields(pg, "a"))
newcolumns
# [1] "col2"
addqry <- paste("alter table some_table",
                paste("add", newcolumns, dbDataType(pg, b[,newcolumns]),
                      collapse = ", "))
addqry
# [1] "alter table some_table add col2 DOUBLE PRECISION"
dbExecute(pg, addqry)
dbWriteTable(pg, "some_table", b, append = TRUE)
dbGetQuery(pg, "select * from some_table")
#    no year col1 col2
# 1 234 2012    1   NA
# 2 235 2013    1   NA
# 3 346 2014    1   NA
# 4 333 2014   NA    2
# 5 353 2015   NA    2
# 6 324 2016   NA    2
```